# Centos 7: mv command mishap

Tags: centos, root, mv, vps

I am on a Centos 7 64bit machine on a VPS using VMWare. I was moving some files and I think I may have moved the root directory to some folder. After this was done I could not cd to any directory and rebooted the machine. Now, reading some of the question on SE I see that I should not have rebooted the machine but now as it's done what can be done?

When I boot from the Recovery console from VPS management now it goes into emergency mode and this is the error in journalctl:

```
systemd[1]: Starting Switch Root... 
systemctl[500]: Failed to switch root: Specif ied switch root path /sys
systemd[1]: initrd-switch-root.service: main process exited, code=exit
systemd[1]: Failed to start Switch Root. 
systemd[1]: Startup f inished in 872ms (kernel) Iinitral 3.81.9s I 
systemd[1]: Unit initrd-switch-root.service entered failed state. 
systemd[1]: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies of initrd-switch-root.s 
systemd[1]: initrd-switch-root.service failed. 
systemd[1]: Started Emergency Shell. systemdI11: Reached target Emergency Mode. 
systemd[1]: Received SIGIMIIIM.21 from PIO 263 Iplymouthal. 
kernel: random: crng init done
```

On rebooting there are few options to choose from as below but all go to the shell:

[image]

[image]

Any idea what to do? I have some websites hosted on this server and would like to get them back.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: fixed the big block to text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so after hours of searching around I finally got it back. Here's what I did:

From the bash prompt pictured in my original question a ls showed a directory listing with included a directory called `sysroot`. `cd`'d into the directory and voila found it was the / of the OS files. I noticed a lot of the folders were missing and only a few remained from wherein I initiated the `mv` command. So I got into the directory where the `mv` command was done and sure enough the following folders were in the same directory. I tried moving them back but the file system was read-only error came up when moving files. Followed advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117950/how-do-i-change-file-system-in-recovery-mode-to-read-write-mode) on changing `ro` to `rw` after pressing `e` on the OS install list  and then moved them all to `/sysroot`. Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX8RH.jpg)

> etc
> home
> lib
> lib64
> lost+found
> media
> mnt
> opt
> root
> sbin
> srv
> var

Rebooted and it wouldn't go past the Cento 7 progress bar after the progress bar filled up. Pressed Escape and found the error: Failed to mount /boot. Wouldn't go to a prompt even. Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv0p5.jpg).

Followed the advise [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9D3hvnnby9A) on adding `init=/bin/bash` and again changed `ro` to `rw` on the kernel line by pressing `e` on the OS selection list and it booted back to bash prompt. From there again checked and I missed the `bin` folder in the old `mv` from location. `mv`'d that back to `/sysroot`. I then checked the `/boot` folder under `/sysroot` but it was empty. Not knowing if the files were deleted or misplaced I was searching for the same online and found someone had commented

> /boot is normally on a separate partition so by mounting /mnt/sysimage you will not see the files under /boot

so I rebooted and bingo everything works. Booted straight into the login prompt. Tried SSHing and works too. All websites are up too. Great result! Thanks for all the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: +1 just for hanging on in and fixing it. No -1 for being a numpty because any one of  us who claims not to have done something similar at least once is telling porkies